# Adding Single character to string each time function runs and returning once length is 4, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am very new to python and struggling with a keypad function

The below code is me trying to grab individual number inputs from a membrane keypad and pass them into a variable. When doing so I need to keep adding the new character to the variable ‘finalPW’ until it is 4 characters long and then I need to return it to be used in a function that compares it to a list of other strings.

My issue is that the variable is either reset each time when declared locally, so I only ever get one digit, or it simply states that the ‘finalPW’ variable is referenced before its assigned.

I am trying very hard to avoid the use of globals as have been informed this is bad practice.

Many Thanks in Advance!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

MATRIX = [['D', '#', '0', '*'],
          ['C', '9', '8', '7'],
          ['B', '6', '5', '4'],
          ['A', '3', '2', '1']]

COL = [21, 20, 16, 26]
ROW = [19, 13, 6, 5]


def passwordinit():
    finalPW = ""
    return finalPW



for j in range(4):
     GPIO.setup(COL[j], GPIO.OUT)
     GPIO.output(COL[j], 1)

for i in range(4):
    GPIO.setup(ROW[i],GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)



def keypadcharacter():
    finalPW = ""
    if len(finalPW) < 4:
        try:
                while (True):
                    for j in range(4):
                        GPIO.output(COL[j] ,0)
                        for i in range (4):
                             if GPIO.input(ROW[i]) ==0:
                                pwS = MATRIX[i][j]
                                time.sleep(0.5)
                                finalPW += pwS
                                print finalPW
                                while(GPIO.input(ROW[i]) ==0):
                                    pass
                        GPIO.output(COL[j],1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
             GPIO.cleanup()
        return finalPW
    else:
        print finalpw

passwordinit()
keypadcharacter()
```

Comment: If you want the variable to be accessible (or to even exist) outside of the function that set it, you need to declare it as `global`.

Comment: OK, from my research it suggested that if I could return the variable from a function I could avoid globals? So is there not really a way to achieve what I want without using a global do you think?

Comment: Certainly you could return the variable from a function.  It's then your responsibility to *actually do something with that value* (you're just throwing away the return value from your functions), including passing it as a parameter to the other functions that need it.  In other words, the mere act of returning a variable doesn't make it globally available.

Comment: Ahhhhhh that makes more sense. So can I return it to the  keypadcharacter() function so the function starts again with the finalPW variable containing the 1st character for the second to be added ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sussed it!

I separated the two functions and managed to return a single character into a while loop. Code below:

```
def keypad():
    d = 6
    while (d == 6):
        try:
            while(True):
                for j in range(4):
                    GPIO.output(COL[j] ,0)
                    for i in range (4):
                        if GPIO.input(ROW[i]) ==0:
                            x = MATRIX[i][j]
                            return x
                            while (GPIO.input(ROW[i])==0):
                                pass
                    GPIO.output(COL[j],1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            GPIO.cleanup()


def alarm():
    finalpw = ""
    while len(finalpw) < 4:
       digit = keypad()
       time.sleep(0.5)
       if digit != "":
           finalpw+=digit
           print digit
```

Hope this helps someone else!